# General expressions for $\mathcal{L}(n)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)^n\text{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals, polylogarithm

Define $$\operatorname{Ci}(x)=-\int_{x}^{
\infty} \frac{\cos(y)}{y}\text{d}y.$$
It is easy to show
$$
\mathcal{L}(1)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)\text{d}x=0
$$
and
$$\mathcal{L}(2)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)^2\text{d}x
=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
$\mathcal{L}(3),\mathcal{L}(4)$ is a little bit non-trivial. We have two claims(take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391036/) to find more details):
$$\begin{aligned}
&\mathcal{L}(3)=-\frac{3\pi}{2}\ln2 \\
&\mathcal{L}(4)=3\pi\operatorname{Li}_2
\left ( \frac{2}{3}  \right )+\frac{3\pi}{2}\ln^23
\end{aligned}$$
Where $\operatorname{Li}$ are *polylogarithms*, they are defined by $\displaystyle{\operatorname{Li}_n(z)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k^n}}$ for $|z|<1$.
$\mathcal{L}(5)$ is much more non-trivial. We have
$$
\mathcal{L}(5)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)^5\text{d}x
=-\frac{15\pi^3}{8}\ln(2)-\frac{15\pi}{2}\ln(2)^3
-\frac{45\pi}{4}\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )\ln(2)
-\frac{45\pi}{4}\operatorname{Li}_3\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right ) 
-\frac{15\pi}{16}\zeta(3).
$$
Where $\zeta(n)=\operatorname{Li}_n(1)$ for $\Re(n)>1$.
**My question:**
How can we find alternate generalizations? I believe that $\mathcal{L}(6)$ can be expressed by using ordinary polylogarithms($\mathcal{L}(7)$ seems impossible). We can also find the *closed-forms* of following integrals:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)^4\cos(x)\text{d}x,\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)^2\frac{\operatorname{Si}(2x)}{x} \cos(x)\text{d}x$$
where $\displaystyle{\operatorname{Si}(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\text{d}t}.$

---

**Update 1:**
Define $\operatorname{si}(x)+\operatorname{Si}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Here are some results:
$$\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{si}(x)\text{d}x=1\\
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{si}(x)^2\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{si}(x)^3\text{d}x=\frac{\pi^2}{4} -\frac{3}{2}\ln^22-\frac{3}{4} 
\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )\\
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{si}(x)^4\text{d}x=
\frac{\pi^3}{4} -3\pi\ln^22-\frac{3\pi}{2} 
\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )
\end{aligned}$$

---

**Update 2:** A useful fourier transform
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)^3\cos(a x)\text{d}x
=\begin{cases}
\color{Red}{\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-a}{3}\right)}{4 a}}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a-1}{a-2}\right)}{2 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+1}{3 (a-1)}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a-1}{a+1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+1}{a+2}\right)}{2 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+1}{3}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+1}{a-1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a-1}{3 (a+1)}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log ^2(2-a)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log ^2(a+2)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (3) \log (a-1)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (3) \log \left(\frac{a+2}{a+1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (3) \log (a-2)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (3) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{2 a} &  (0\le a\le1),\\
\color{Red}{\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2-1}\right)}{4 a}}+\frac{\pi  \log \left(-\frac{a}{a+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{1-a^2}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{a}{2}\right)}{2 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2(1-a)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+2}{2 (1-a)}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{3}{a-1}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+2}{2 (a+1)}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a (a+2)}{(a+1)^2}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1-a}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{a-1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{a-1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2(-a)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{a+1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{3 \pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{7 \pi ^3}{24 a}+\frac{3 \pi  \log ^2(2)}{8 a}+\frac{\pi  \log ^2(a)}{8 a}-\frac{\pi  \log ^2(a+1)}{2 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (2) \log (a-1)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (2) \log (a+1)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (2) \log (a)}{2 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (2) \log (a+2)}{2 a}+\frac{\pi  \log \left(\frac{a+2}{a+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log \left(-\frac{1}{a+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{a (a+2)}{(a+1)^2}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (3) \log (a+2)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (a) \log (a+2)}{2 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (a) \log (a+1)}{2 a}-\frac{i \pi ^2 \log \left(\frac{1}{1-a}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (3) \log (a-1)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log \left(-\frac{1}{a+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{a+2}{a+1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log \left(-\frac{1}{a+1}\right) \log \left(-\frac{a}{a+1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (a-1) \log (a+2)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (a+1) \log (a+2)}{4 a}  & (1\le a\le3),  \\
  \color{Red}{-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2-1}\right)}{4 a}}-\frac{\pi  \log \left(-\frac{a}{a+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{1-a^2}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2(-2)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2(2)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1-a}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{a-1}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{a-1}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{a-1}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{a+1}\right)}{2 a}+\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)}{2 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{a}{2}\right)}{2 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2(1-a)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+2}{2 (1-a)}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a-2}{a-1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{3}{a-1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2(a-1)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+2}{2 (a+1)}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a (a+2)}{(a+1)^2}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi ^3}{3 a}-\frac{\pi  \log ^2(2)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log ^2(a+1)}{2 a}+\frac{i \pi ^2 \log (2)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (2) \log (a)}{2 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (2) \log (a+2)}{2 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (2) \log (a-1)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (2) \log (a+1)}{4 a}+\frac{i \pi ^2 \log \left(\frac{1}{1-a}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (3) \log (a-2)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (a-2) \log (a-1)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log \left(\frac{a+2}{a+1}\right) \log \left(-\frac{1}{a+1}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log \left(-\frac{1}{a+1}\right) \log \left(-\frac{a}{a+1}\right)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (a-1) \log (a+2)}{4 a}+\frac{\pi  \log (a+1) \log (a+2)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (a) \log (a+2)}{2 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (a-2) \log \left(\frac{1}{a-1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (3) \log \left(\frac{a+2}{a-1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (2-a) \log (a-1)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (a) \log \left(\frac{1}{a+1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (3) \log \left(\frac{a-2}{a+1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log \left(\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}\right) \log \left(\frac{a+2}{a+1}\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log (3) \log (a+1)}{4 a}-\frac{\pi  \log \left(-\frac{1}{a+1}\right) \log \left(\frac{a (a+2)}{(a+1)^2}\right)}{4 a}& (a\ge3).
\end{cases}$$

---

**Update 3:** Common fourier transforms
$$\begin{aligned}
&1.\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)\cos(\omega x)\text{d}x=
\begin{cases}
  0 &(0\le\omega<1), \\
\displaystyle{ -\frac{\pi}{4}  }&(\omega=1), \\
\displaystyle{ -\frac{\pi}{2\omega}  }&(\omega>1).
\end{cases}\\
&2.\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)\sin(\omega x)\text{d}x=
\begin{cases}
 \displaystyle{-\frac{\ln(1-\omega^2)}{2\omega}}  &(0\le\omega<1), \\
\displaystyle{ +\infty  }&(\omega=1), \\
\displaystyle{-\frac{\ln(\omega^2-1)}{2\omega} }&(\omega>1).
\end{cases}\\
&3.\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)^2\cos(\omega x)\text{d}x=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle{ \frac{\pi\ln(1+\omega)}{2\omega} }&(0\le\omega\le2), \\
\displaystyle{ \frac{\pi\ln(\omega^2-1)}{2\omega} }&(\omega\ge2).
\end{cases}\\
&4.\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{si}(x)\sin(\omega x)\text{d}x=
\begin{cases}
  0 &(0\le\omega<1), \\
\displaystyle{ \frac{\pi}{4}  }&(\omega=1), \\
\displaystyle{ \frac{\pi}{2\omega}  }&(\omega>1).
\end{cases}\\
&5.\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{si}(x)\cos(\omega x)\text{d}x=
\begin{cases}
 \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2\omega}\ln\left ( \frac{1+\omega}{1-\omega}  \right ) }  &(0\le\omega<1), \\
\displaystyle{ +\infty  }&(\omega=1), \\
\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2\omega}\ln\left ( \frac{\omega+1}{\omega-1}  \right ) }&(\omega>1).
\end{cases}\\
&6.\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{si}(x)^2\cos(\omega x)\text{d}x=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle{ \frac{\pi\ln(1+\omega)}{2\omega} }&(0\le\omega\le2), \\
\displaystyle{ \frac{\pi}{2\omega}\ln\left ( \frac{\omega+1}{\omega-1}  \right ) }&(\omega\ge2).
\end{cases}\\
&7.\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Si}(x)}{x}\cos(\omega x)\text{d}x=
\begin{cases}
 \displaystyle{-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\omega)}  &(0<\omega\le1), \\
\displaystyle{0 }&(\omega\ge1).
\end{cases}\\
\end{aligned}$$

---

**Definition:** Functions $\operatorname{Si}_n(x)$ are defined by
$$\operatorname{Si}_0(x)=\sin(x),\operatorname{Si}_n(x)
=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\operatorname{Si}_{n-1}(t)}{t}\text{d}t.$$
And we are able to get
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Si}_2(x)\operatorname{si}(x)^2}{x}
\text{d} x=\frac{7\pi^5}{1440}.
$$

Comment: +1 Great achievement when compared to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391036/a-closed-form-expression-for-the-integral-int-0-infty-textci3x-mat

Comment: Might be interesting: the asymptotic behaviour of $\mathcal{L}(n)$ for $n$ $\to \infty$ is $(-1)^n c \; n!$ where $c\simeq 0.56146$ is a constant whose closed form is to be found.

Comment: I didn't manage $\int_{0}^{\infty} (\text{Si}(x)-\frac{\pi}{2})^3 \;dx$, did you do?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze The absolute value is$$\frac{\pi^2}{4} -\frac{3}{2}\ln^22-\frac{3}{4} 
\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right ).$$

Comment: I posted an evaluation of $\mathcal{L}(4)$ as an answer to the other question.  It seemed more appropriate to post it there since this question is about $\mathcal{L}(n), n \ge 6.$

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze The constant in your asymptotic approximation should be $c = \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma}$ with the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$. This is related to the asymptotic expansion of $\operatorname{Ci}$ near the origin.

Comment: For the Fouriertransform 3. I find $\frac{\pi}{2 \omega} \log(\frac{1-\omega}{1+\omega}), -1 \lt \omega \lt 1$, $\frac{\pi}{2 \omega} \log(\omega^2-1)$, $\omega>2$

Comment: I tried $\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{si}(x)^5\; dx$ but partial integration resulted in two mutually equivalent integrals, between which the partial integration went to and fro..

Comment: The body of the question now gets quite long, it's better to post your evaluation of $\mathcal{L}$ in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

---

*(added on Jan.08, 22)*: Closed-forms of $\mathcal{L}(m,n)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)^m\operatorname{si}(x)^n\text{d}x$(notice: $\operatorname{si}(x)=\operatorname{Si}(x)-\frac\pi2$).
\begin{align}
&\left\{\begin{aligned}
 \mathcal{L}(1,0)=0,\qquad\mathcal{L}(0,1)=-1.\end{aligned}\right.\\
&\left\{\begin{aligned}\mathcal{L}(2,0)=\frac\pi2,\qquad \mathcal{L}(1,1)=\ln(2),\qquad\mathcal{L}(0,2)=\frac\pi2.\end{aligned}\right.\\
&\left\{\begin{aligned}&\mathcal{L}(3,0)=-\frac{3\pi}{2}\ln(2),\\
&\mathcal{L}(2,1)=-\frac34\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac14 \right )-\frac32\ln(2)^2 -\frac{\pi^2}{12},\\
&\mathcal{L}(1,2)=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2),\\
&\mathcal{L}(0,3)=\frac34\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac14 \right )+\frac32\ln(2)^2 -\frac{\pi^2}{4}.\end{aligned}\right.\\
&\left\{\begin{aligned}&\mathcal{L}(4,0)=\frac{3\pi}{2}\operatorname{Li}_2
\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )+3\pi\ln(2)^2+\frac{\pi^3}{4},\\
&\mathcal{L}(3,1)=\frac{15}{4}\operatorname{Li}_3\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right ) 
-\frac{5}{8}\zeta(3)+\frac{15}{4}\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )\ln(2)+\frac{5}{2}\ln(2)^3
+\frac{\pi^2}{2}\ln(2),\\
&\mathcal{L}(2,2)=\frac{\pi^3}{12},\\
&\mathcal{L}(1,3)=-\frac{9}{4}\operatorname{Li}_3\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right ) 
+\frac{21}{8}\zeta(3)-\frac{9}{4}\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )\ln(2)-\frac{3}{2}\ln(2)^3,\\
&\mathcal{L}(0,4)=-\frac{3\pi}{2}\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac14 \right )-3\pi\ln(2)^2 +
\frac{\pi^3}{4}.\end{aligned}\right.\\
&\left\{\begin{aligned}&\mathcal{L}(5,0)=-\frac{45\pi}{4}\operatorname{Li}_3\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right ) 
-\frac{15\pi}{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{45\pi}{4}\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )\ln(2)-\frac{15\pi}{2}\ln(2)^3
-\frac{15\pi^3}{8}\ln(2),\\
&\mathcal{L}(3,2)=\frac{3\pi}{4}\operatorname{Li}_3\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right ) 
-\frac{29\pi}{16}\zeta(3)+\frac{3\pi}{4}\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )\ln(2)+\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2)^3
-\frac{\pi^3}{8}\ln(2),\\
&\mathcal{L}(1,4)=\frac{15\pi}{4}\operatorname{Li}_3\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right ) 
-\frac{55\pi}{16}\zeta(3)+\frac{15\pi}{4}\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )\ln(2)+\frac{5\pi}{2}\ln(2)^3
+\frac{\pi^3}{8}\ln(2).
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{align}

> *Sketch of evaluation*:
> The following two relations are true.
> $$\begin{aligned}
> &\mathcal{L}(3,1)-\mathcal{L}(1,3) = \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ei}(-x)^4\text{d}x=6\operatorname{Li}_3\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right ) 
> -\frac{13}{4}\zeta(3)+6\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )\ln(2)+4\ln(2)^3+\frac{\pi^2}{2}\ln(2),\\
> &\mathcal{L}(3,1)+\mathcal{L}(1,3)
> =3\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left ( 1+\frac{1}{x}  \right ) }{(1+2x)^2} \left ( \frac{\pi^2}{12}-\ln(x)\ln(1+x)+\ln(x)^2
> +\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( -\frac1x \right )   \right )\mathrm{d}x=\frac{3}{2}\operatorname{Li}_3\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right ) 
> +2\zeta(3)+\frac{3}{2}\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )\ln(2)+\ln(2)^3+\frac{\pi^2}{2}\ln(2).
> \end{aligned}$$
> The first equality is evaluated in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301728/).
> The second one is mechanically evaluated by the `MZIntegrate` command.(In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763243/) occured first)
> Other relations:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &\mathcal{L}(5,0)+2\mathcal{L}(3,2)+\mathcal{L}(1,4)=-4\pi
> \left ( \mathcal{L}(3,1)+\mathcal{L}(1,3) \right ) ,\\
> &\mathcal{L}(5,0)-2\mathcal{L}(3,2)-3\mathcal{L}(1,4)
> =-4\pi\left ( \mathcal{L}(3,1)-\mathcal{L}(1,3) \right ) .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Since $\mathcal{L}(5,0),\mathcal{L}(1,3),\mathcal{L}(3,1)$ have closed-forms, $\mathcal{L}(3,2),\mathcal{L}(1,4)$ can be found.

---

*(add on Jan.10, 22)*: For $(4,1),(2,3),(0,5)$,  we have no simple result. We need to compute some weight 4 logarithm integrals but we don't expect irreducible CMZVs. And as they do, $\mathcal{L}(m,n),m+n\ge6$ do not have good results either.

- If $m$ is even, then $(m,n)$ can be calculated by lower $(a,b),a+b=m+n-1$ with odd $b$. For example, to evaluate $(5,0),(3,2),(1,4)$, we use values of $(3,1),(1,3)$. This is generally true for higher $m+n$.
- To go further, we detect a sophisticated integral,
  $$
  \small\int_{0}^{\infty}\left ( \operatorname{Ci}(x)^2+\operatorname{si}(x)^2\right )^2\left ( 
   \operatorname{Ci}(x)^2+\operatorname{si}(x)^2+3\pi\operatorname{si}(x)\right ) \text{d}x
  =6\pi^3\operatorname{Li}_2\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right ) +12\pi^3\ln(2)^2.
  $$
- This only shows the simplest cases. Integrals $\int_{0}^{\infty}
  \operatorname{Ci}(x)\operatorname{Ci}(ax)\operatorname{Ci}(bx)
  \operatorname{Ci}(cx)\operatorname{Ci}(dx)\text{d}x$ no doubt have similar expressions. But it will be very long.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an evaluation of $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \operatorname{Si}(x)- \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^{3} \, \mathrm dx,$$ which was asked about in the comments and mentioned in **Update.1**.

Integrating by parts twice, we get $$\begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\operatorname{Si}(x) - \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^{3} \, \mathrm dx  &= -\frac{3 \pi^{2}}{4} - 3\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2x)\left(\operatorname{Si}(x) - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{x} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= -\frac{3 \pi^{2}}{4} - 3 J, \end{align} $$

where

$ \begin{align} J&= -\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (2x)}{x} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (xt)}{t}  \, \mathrm dt \, \mathrm dx \\ & \overset{(1)}{=} -\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2x)\sin (tx)}{x}  \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dt \\ &= -\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left( (2-t)x\right) - \cos \left((2+t)x \right)}{x}  \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dt  \\ &\overset{(2)}{=} \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} \ln \left(\frac{|2-t|}{2+t} \right)\, \mathrm dt \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\int_{1}^{2}  \frac{1}{t} \ln \left(\frac{2-t}{2+t} \right)\, \mathrm dt +\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} \ln \left(\frac{t-2}{2+t} \right)\, \mathrm dt \right) \\ & \overset{(3)}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2} \left(  \frac{1}{t} \ln \left(\frac{2-t}{2+t} \right)\, \mathrm dt + \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{1}{v} \ln \left(\frac{1-2v}{1+2v} \right) \, \mathrm dv \right)  \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{1}^{2}\frac{\ln(2-t)}{t} \, \mathrm dt- \int_{1}^{2} \frac{\ln(2+t)}{t} \, \mathrm dt + \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\ln(1-2v)}{v} \, \mathrm dv - \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\ln(1+2v)}{v} \, \mathrm dv \right) \\ & \overset{(4)}{=}  \frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{1}^{2}\frac{\ln \left(1- \frac{t}{2}\right)}{t} \, \mathrm dt- \int_{1}^{2} \frac{\ln(1+ \frac{t}{2})}{t} \mathrm dt + \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\ln(1-2v)}{v} \, \mathrm dv - \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\ln(1+2v)}{v} \, \mathrm dv \right) \\ & \overset{(5)}{=} \frac{1}{2} \left( -\operatorname{Li}_{2} (1) + \operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) + \operatorname{Li}_{2} (-1) - \operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(- \frac{1}{2} \right)- \operatorname{Li}_{2} (1)+ \operatorname{Li}_{2} (-1) \right) \\ & \overset{(6)}{=} \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{\pi^{2}}{2} + \operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) - \operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(- \frac{1}{2} \right)\right) \\ & \overset{(7)}{=} \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{\pi^{2}}{2}+ 2 \operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)- \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1}{4} \right) \right) \\ & \overset{(8)}{=} \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{\pi^{2}}{3}-  \ln^{2}(2) - \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1}{4} \right) \right). \end{align} $

Therefore, $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\operatorname{Si}(x)- \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^{3} \, \mathrm dx &= - \frac{3 \pi^{2}}{4} - \frac{3}{2} \left(-\frac{\pi^{2}}{3}-  \ln^{2}(2) - \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1}{4} \right)  \right) \\ &= - \frac{\pi^{2}}{4} + \frac{3}{2} \ln^{2}(2) + \frac{3}{4} \operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\frac{1}{4} \right). \end{align}$$

---

$(1)$ Switching the order of integration is justified by [Plancherel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Plancherel_theorem_and_Parseval%27s_theorem) in the [form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12579) $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \hat{g}(x) \, \mathrm dx  = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{f}(\omega) g(\omega) \, d \omega,  $ which holds if $f$ and $g$ are square-integrable functions.

$(2)$ [Generalized Frullani integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/449934)

$(3)$ Make the substitution $v= \frac{1}{t}$ in the second integral.

$(4)$ $\ln(2-t) = \ln(2) + \ln \left(1-\frac{t}{2} \right)$ and $\ln(2+t)= \ln(2)+ \ln \left(1+\frac{t}{2} \right)$

$(5)$ $-\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\ln(1-yt)}{t}  = - \int_{0}^{xy} \frac{\ln(1-u)}{u} \, \mathrm du =  \operatorname{Li}_{2}(xy)$

$(6)$ $\operatorname{Li}_{2}(1) = \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$ and $\operatorname{Li}_{2}(-1) = - \eta(2) = - \frac{\pi^{2}}{12}$

$(7)$ [Dilogarithm duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Polylogarithm)

$(8)$ [Special values of the dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function#Special_values)

Comment: +1 I have found the same result by repeated partial integration making a list of integrals I have already solved. There is just one non trovial integral remaining. This could be done by Mathematica. I tend to consider the task of finding a closed expression as heuristic. It need not be rigurous it can use tools like Mathematica and others. Once you have found the expression your can verify it numerically.